# Find two positive constant that the integral inequality holds

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Let U be the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $L$ be the following differential operator acting on functions $u:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:
>   $$Lu=-u_{xx}-u_{yy}+(\sin y)u_x+(\cos x)u_y$$
>   Let $L_{\mu}=L+\mu I$ and let $B_{\mu}$ be the bilinear form associated with $L_\mu$. Compute reasonable positive constants $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ such that 
>   $$B_\mu[u,u]\geq \epsilon_1||u||^2_{H^1_0(U)}-\epsilon_2||u||^2_{L^2}$$
>   (be clear how these constants depend on $\mu$). Give a reasonably precise range of values of $\mu$ for which $B_\mu$ is coercive.

---

My attempt: By definition, it is clear that
$$B_\mu[u,u]=\int u_xu_x+u_yu_y+(\sin y)u_x u+(\cos x)u_y u +\mu u^2$$
and 
$$\epsilon_1||u||^2_{H^1_0(U)}-\epsilon_2||u||^2_{L^2}=\epsilon_1\int (u^2+u_x^2+u_y^2)\ dx-\epsilon_2\int u^2\ dx$$
So the inequality becomes
$$\int u_x^2+u_y^2+(\sin y)u_x u+(\cos x)u_y u +\mu u^2\ dx\\ \geq \epsilon_1\int (u_x^2+u_y^2)\ dx+(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2)\int u^2\ dx$$
Now I don't know how to continue and how to deal with the term "$(\sin y)u_x u+(\cos x)u_y u$".

Any hints or answers are welcome!

Comment: On these terms you can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.